# class for link not working with CSS

Tags: html, css

I've assigned the class "greenbutton" to a link in my html, but none of the changes I make to this class on my CSS take effect.

**home.html.erb**

```
<p><a class="greenbutton" href="#">Sign Up</a> to learn more</p>
```

**custom.css.scss**

```
.greenbutton a:link, .greenbutton a:visited {
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

The weird thing about this is that when I assign this class to the preceding paragraph tag, the changes take effect. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CSS you're trying should either be applied to the `<p>` or modified to `a.greenbutton`. What you're specifying is an anchor within an element classed `greenbutton`. e.g.

```
.greenbutton a { } /* anchor inside .greenbutton-classed element, like:

  <p class="greenbutton">
    <a href="#">Foo</a>
  </p>

*/

a.greenbutton { } /* anchor with .greenbutton class applied, like:

  <a href="#" class="greenbutton">Bar</a>

*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is wrong:

```
.greenbutton a:link
```

This targets anchor links within an element that has the class "greenbutton". What you want is for the class to be on the anchor:

```
a.greenbutton:link
```

Answer (score 2):

Css class should be like this.

```
a.greenbutton, a.greenbutton:visited {
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: The first selector, is critical (a.greenbutton). If you start this by adding the pseudo-class first (:visited), it won't work.